# Типизированные поля классов

Tags: php

Не подскажете, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Использую PHP 7.4.4. Как только в классе указываю на тип какого-либо поля - так сразу скрипт не работает. Сколько сайтов перерыл, везде пишут, что PHP 7.4 поддерживает типизацию полей. Более того, PHPStorm мне и сам советует указать тип поля (подчеркивает с предложением указать тип).

Пример того, как я использую:

```
class SomeClass {
    private string $user;
}
```

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что не работает? Где как чем запускаете, какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: `echo 'test1';
new SomeClass();
echo 'test2';`

Вот 'test2' я уже не вижу, а 'test1' - вижу.

Скрипт находится на моем сервере (именно там я и проверяю, какая версия PHP у меня стоит через консоль (`php -v`). Ну, соответственно, по ссылке в браузере перехожу по типу mysite.ru/script.php и вижу 'test1'.

Comment: В моём PHP 7.4 отлично работает, печатается `test1test2` без ошибок. Что нужно  сделать, чтобы перестало работать?

Comment: «по ссылке в браузере перехожу» — а вы уверены, что веб-сервер запускает ту же самую версию PHP? Откуда у вас веб-сервер, как он настроен и соединён с PHP?

Comment: При создании экземпляра класса перестает скрипт работать

Comment: Я создал экземпляр класса и у меня скрипт продолжил отлично работать. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Веб-сервер... Ну, приобрел. ОС - Ubuntu. Загружаю файлы туда через FileZilla (ну, и автоматический загрузчик у PHPStorm). Версию получаю через консоль это сервера, вводя `php -v`. Ответ: `PHP 7.4.4 (clio) ...`

Comment: @andreymal, все Вы правильно делаете. Может быть просто PHP на другую версию сменить попробовать?

Comment: Ubuntu это операционная система, а не веб-сервер. А веб-сервер на этой убунте какой и откуда взялся?

Comment: На IPServer приобретен веб-сервер.

Comment: О каком IPServer речь?

Comment: Ммм. К сожалению, видимо, я Вас мало понимаю) У меня есть VPS-сервер. Непосредственно на нем ОС Ubuntu.

Comment: ОС Ubuntu по умолчанию не содержит в себе никакого веб-сервера и не может открываться по ссылкам в браузере. Значит кто-то специально установил какой-то веб-сервер. А кто и какой, и какая версия PHP настроена в этом веб-сервере — это вы должны знать изначально. Если не знаете, то помочь будет очень трудно

Comment: Может быть Вы имеете в виду панельку Vesta?

Comment: Vesta для своей работы тоже требует установленный и настроенный веб-сервер, так что вопрос по-прежнему остался — какой веб-сервер установлен и как настроен.

Comment: Может быть тогда речь идет об apache-2?) Версии 2.4.29

Comment: Ага, а как к этому apache2 подключен PHP?

Comment: Господи. Вместо "типизованных полей класса", которые тебе все равно не для реальной пользы, а как цветные фантики, потому что красиво, надо сначала научиься **базовым** вещам. Как смотреть ошибки в **логе веб-сервера**. Как смотреть версию РНР в **phpinfo()**. Как потом гуглить вопрос "в консоли и на веб-сервере разные версии пхп". Ну или ту ошибку, которая в логе, если версии не при чем. Потому что **сначала в любом случае надо смотреть в лог**, а не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @andreymal, благодаря Вам понял, в какую сторону нужно рыть. В итоге пришел к положительному результату (в виде ответа оформил). Спасибо Вам больше за помощь. Ну, и теперь я знаю, что Apache2 - сервер :) От WEB-разработки я крайне далек, поэтому плаваю в элементарных для Вас вещах. Мне буквально приходиться ковыряться в WEB-разработке, ибо сам я гораздо ближе к Си-подобным языкам.

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Насчет типизации, просто очень удобно понимать, что представляет из себя та или иная переменная. Да и помогает предотвращать ошибки. Опять же, насчет базовых вещей, я далек от WEB-разработки, поэтому есть много трудностей. Но ничего, все впереди еще. Отдельное спасибо за phpinfo() - именно там я узнал, какую версию PHP использует Apache2.

Comment: @Ипатьев, простите, не удержался, решил еще дополнить. Я бы с удовольствием искал как раз что-то вроде "в консоли и на веб-сервере разные версии PHP" - к счастью, в гугле пока не забанили, - но на момент создания темы я считал, что если в консоли отображена версия php7.4, то она везде и используется. То, что в консоли одна, а на сервере - другая, для меня, откровенно говоря, большое открытие. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий шаг показал мне, какую версию PHP использует Apache2:

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Результат: PHP 7.2.
Для смены версии на PHP 7.4 потребовалось установить пакет:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

После установки пакета Apache2 стал использовать нужную версию PHP, благодаря чему проблема разрешилась.